# c# threading in setter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Using c#, in visual studio 2015 community, trying to convert code that converts a base64 encoded string to an image into a threaded task to reduce bottlenecks.

this is the code that works:

```
    private string _logoBase64;
    public string logoBase64
    {
        get { return _logoBase64; }
        set
        {
            _logoBase64 = value;
            setLogo();
        }
    }
    public ImageSource logo { get; set; }
            private void setLogo()
    {
        if ((this.logoBase64 != null) && (this.logoBase64.Length > 0))
        {
            string _logoBase64 = this.logoBase64
                .Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
                .Replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "")
                .Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            try
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(_logoBase64));
                image.EndInit();
                this.logo = image;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.Errors.Add(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                if (Program.environment == "development")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873177(v=vs.110).aspx) example, i tried to convert it to a threaded task:

```
    internal Task setLogoASync(string b64, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var image = new BitmapImage(); 
            if ((b64 != null) && (b64.Length > 0))
            {
                b64 = b64
                    .Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
                    .Replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "")
                    .Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");

                try
                {
                    image.BeginInit();
                    image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(b64));
                    image.EndInit();
                    this.logo = image;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Program.Errors.Add(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                    if (Program.environment == "development")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.logo = image;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
```

but the problem is the setter has to be async, but it can't be.  is there a way around this?

Comment: the general recommendation for setters is that they should only be used for very short running operations. It would be better to remove it altogether and just provide a public method instead

Comment: you can use a thread or BackgroundWorker in the setter for that....and let the setter proceed without halting your GUI

Comment: Saad Mind telling me exactly how?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah Still a bad practice. I wouldn't assume a property setter would create a thread. If it does, then convert it to method and return a `Task`.

Comment: @SaadAbdullah a Task is a higher level abstraction for a Thread. The problem isn't the use of Tasks, in fact your suggestion would add more problems.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys thanks for your suggestion and insights. i took another tack and have it working now in a thread.  if you made that an answer i would accept it. pete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general recommendation for setters is that they should only be used for very short running operations.

It would be better to remove it altogether and just provide a public method instead.

The reason for that is that as a programmer I shouldn't need to think about unexpected implications and side effects of calling a setter.

Having the setter creating a thread is such an unexpected implication in terms of computing time and used resources (eg. CPU and memory).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to calculate the Base64 implementation each time the image is modified, use `Lazy<T>` to calculate it the first time it's actually request.

```
private Lazy<ImageSource > _image;
public ImageSource logo
{
    get { return _image.Value; }
}

private string _logoBase64;
public string logoBase64
{
    get { return _logoBase64; }
    set
    {
        _logoBase64 = value;
        //Can't reset a Lazy, so we create a new one.
        _image=new Lazy<ImageSource>(()=>imageFromBase64()));
    }
}

//Initialize the Lazy in the constructor
public MyClass()
{
    _image=new Lazy<ImageSource>(()=>imageFromBase64())l
}

ImageSource imageFromBase64()
{
   var image = new BitmapImage(); 
   if ((b64 != null) && (b64.Length > 0))
   {
            b64 = b64
                .Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
                .Replace("data:image/gif;base64,", "")
                .Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");

            try
            {
                image.BeginInit();
                image.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(b64));
                image.EndInit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.Errors.Add(e.Message + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
                if (Program.environment == "development")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
    }
    return image;
}
```

To avoid delays even for the first `logo` request, you can initiate lazy evaluation in a throwaway task. Lazy ensures concurrent access to its contents so it doesn't matter whether the task completes or not before someone requests the logo

```
public string logoBase64
{
    get { return _logoBase64; }
    set
    {
        _logoBase64 = value;
        //Can't reset a Lazy, so we create a new one.
        var newLazy=new Lazy<ImageSource>(()=>imageFromBase64()));
        //Start throwaway task before assigning to backing field,
        //to avoid race conditions
        Task.Run(()=>newLazy.Value);
        _image=newLazy;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a great idea, but the code supplied doesn't work, and I can't see how to fix it.  private Lazy<ImageSource > _image=new Lazy<ImageSource>(()=>imageFromBase64());  = a field initializer cannot reference the non-static  field, method, or property 'User.ImageFromBae64()

Comment: Initialize it in your constructor.